# SODA dll in Script Task

Tags: ssis, socrata, soda

I am trying to download some of the data from Data.Medicare.Gov using SODA APIs in an SSIS package. Is there a strongly named version of SODA.dll that I can install in the GAC?  The Script Task loses the reference otherwise. Note: 
When I tried using the OData connection on a resource path or Collection (e.g., https://data.medicare.gov/OData.svc/xubh-q36u), I get an error: Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager refused). Has anyone come up with an SSIS implementation to download SOCRATA data?

Answer (score 0):

Mary G., I haven't worked with SODA/Socrata in .net recently. When I was able to work with it, I found [this github reference](https://github.com/socrata-archive/soda-dotnet) helpful. You might also consider [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org). I think since the time I worked with Socrata datasets, a SodaDotNet library has been added with a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json. Actually, try Nuget first! :)